# Using NOT in Excel Advanced Filter

Tags: excel

I am just asking whether it is at all possible using Advanced Filter with NOT and unique records? To explain my logic, this is what I am trying to achieve, I have a column called option codes, in this column there are duplicate values and values that have the word "NULL". Now, what I want to do is to filter on this column all unique values but I also want to keep all rows that have the word NULL in that column, too. I want to do this in one filter rather than having to go back and forth.

Is there away to do this?

Example output would be:

```
AA
BB
CC
NULL
NULL
.
.
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you get advance filter http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214324

For `not equal` you can do something like this; for example

```
=if( F5<>35,"Failed","Passed")
```

Comment: Can I ask whether this can be added into the criteria range? My point is that I wish to record the advanced filter as a macro and adding another column is not possible

Comment: Yes, I think you can. Try once.

Comment: I had a go but it said invalid reference